# Seeing TLS error after upgrade to 11.0.15 10LTS

Tags: java

We are seeing issues related to TLS connectivity after container images were built with Java 11.0.15+10LTS.

After following https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5696401 we already have set `security.useSystemPropertiesFile=false` in `${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/java.security` however we are seeing the same symptoms as the KB link.

Multiple applications are unable to start because of TLS errors.
All environments are impacted.
Container continuously crash loopbackoffs. What could be the issue?

Comment: You seem to be using a template for this question. If you didn't come with it by yourself, may I ask where you got it from?

Comment: This also is more of a complaint, than a question. There's no single question mark.

Comment: Looking for help on how to solve this issue with tls errors

Comment: @MartinZeitler I've added the question. Requesting help to solve

Answer (score 0):

Redhat updated a blog post with the solution:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5696401
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6960589
Solution is to set the following env settings:

JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Djava.security.disableSystemPropertiesFile=true"